# Placing a container in a container using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This seems to work just fine - but I am wondering if it is ok to do it like this?

Why am I doing this? The reason is because I would like a background color which is full page width BUT I'd like the content to be within a padded container.

The code I did works - I just wonder if it is valid?

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;color:#494949;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px;padding-bottom:50px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:yellow;">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow - quite surprised that on one has chimed in on this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never put a container inside of a container, read the rules and guidelines of bootstrap.

You can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/31kxamL9/

```
<section style="background-color:#F5F5F5; color:#494949;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px;padding-bottom:50px;">
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```